# Issue with Assembly dependency on MVC application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application => A , and I have a service project inside =>B the same.

B is build in platform target as anycpu. and A project also with the same platform target.

I have added a new project => C which is build in x86 platform. 
I tried to create an object and  call a method inside that project, one class 'test' by making it as start up project and it is working fine.

when am trying create object and run from main MVC application am getting bellow error.

'

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxx_4.0' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

this 'xxx_4.0' assembly is a depandacy of a project C, which is a c++ dll and build in native form [image]

Bellow given assembly log information

> Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = MsgComWrapper_4.0
>    (Partial)
>   WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
>   WRN: Assembly Name: MsgComWrapper_4.0 | Domain ID: 2
>   WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
>   WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
>   WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
>   WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/D Drive/Remisol Work/Back Up/NewDevBranch/dashboard/src/NI.Dashboard.Web/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\D Drive\Remisol Work\Back Up\NewDevBranch\dashboard\src\NI.Dashboard.Web\bin
>
> ## Calling assembly :
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\D Drive\Remisol Work\Back Up\NewDevBranch\dashboard\src\NI.Dashboard.Web\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/ni.dashboard.radvweb/b65b5014/6770e5d4/MsgComWrapper_4.0.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/ni.dashboard.radvweb/b65b5014/6770e5d4/MsgComWrapper_4.0/MsgComWrapper_4.0.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/D Drive/Remisol Work/Back Up/NewDevBranch/dashboard/src/NI.Dashboard.Web/bin/MsgComWrapper_4.0.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

I have tried many ideas like change platforms , publish in x86 etc but am not able to get it fixed.

Please let me know anything I missed. ma not much familiar with c++.

Comment: Might be a long shot, have you tried enabling 32 bit apps on the application pool in IIS?

Comment: @Slicksim thank you I have enabled and now I am able to run my application,  Also able to create object. but when am accessing any method am getting The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. and inner exception as The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.

Comment: You will be better raising a new question for that along with some code of what you are running.  It will get you a better response

Comment: i would create a service project under 32 bit pool and call it from my 64 bit mvc application. it does not make sense to make all your mvc and service project run as 32 bit application because of a single third party library.